# Firebase - Update value of key and how can make chat unread

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I edit value of key. In the picture, I want to update key 1:5 to 1:8.

```
 test = firebase.database().ref('coun/1/');
      test.child($('#slt').val()).once('value', function(snapshot) {
        key = $('#slt').val();
        if (snapshot !== null){
          test.child(key).set({key : snapshot.val() + 1 });
        }
      });
```

In my project, I want to user see chat unread - how can I do it?
EX: user see 5 in name of room chat.
I had setup it with Localstorage but I must run `setTimeout(10000)` to update Localstorage. But I need to use many bandwidth

[image]

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/KmY6Ak6DK7I

Comment: How did you find it? ._.